# I want to point a sub-domain to a new domain address

Tags: subdomain

I'm looking to point a new domain name to my website sub domain address.

So would all I do is buy the new domain name address and use httaccess to tell my site when the new domain name is entered to go to www.newdomain.mydomain.com. How might I go about doing that?

But I'm hoping to have the new domain name address still be shown when they are on my sub domain as this is for a festival I am helping with and they don't need to buy hosting for this short period.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get your new domain name to point to your website you need to:

- configure your domain name to point to your web site IP address
- configure your web server to serve your website when it receives requests to that new domain name

The company from which you buy your new domain name will provide you with a web interface to configure your domain name and make it point to your IP address.

If you're managing your web server yourself, you will need to edit its configuration to add a new named virtualhost for your new domain name (virtualhost directives don't go into .htaccess files). If you're using a shared hosting company, they probably also provide a web interface to configure your web site, so that it accepts requests to your new domain name.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the url to stay as the one a user typed in instead of showing up as your subdomain is to put the whole site in a frame that loads your subdomain inside of it. Some registrars will do this for you so you don't need to pay for extra hosting. If you go with this option, you don't really need a subdomain, though, as you could just put the new pages in a folder off of your main site since visitors won't see the address anyway.

A slightly more elegant solution would simply be to use virtual hosts, if your server has the capability. If you have your own server, they are not hard to set up. If you have a hosting package from a company like godaddy, the company website will often give instructions on how to do this. The idea is that the server will handle the responsibility of routing a query to a specific folder based on the url of the request. Then all you need to do is set up the folder. If you give more specifics about what your hosting setup is, it will be easier to give guidance in this respect.